# Flask: how to override blueprint route?

Tags: python, flask

I have base_blueprint like that:

```
from flask import (
    jsonify,
    Blueprint,
)


class RestBlueprint(object):
    def __init__(self, db_model):
        self.blueprint = Blueprint(db_model.__tablename__, db_model.__tablename__, url_prefix='/' + db_model.__tablename__ + '/')
        self.db_model = db_model

        @self.blueprint.route("/<entity_id>", methods=["GET"])
        def get_by_id(entity_id):
            response = get_item()
            return jsonify(response)
```

I want to inherit this blueprint by other blueprints like that:

```
from rest_blueprint import RestBlueprint

class UserRestBlueprint(RestBlueprint):
    def __init__(self, db_model):
        super(UserRestBlueprint, self).__init__(db_model)

        @self.blueprint.route("/<user_id>", methods=["GET"])
        def get_by_id(user_id):
            response = get_item()
            del response["password"]
            return jsonify(response)
```

This is a basic example and the reason I want to do it that way is to have base blueprint used for most of my models for CRUD and have custom blueprints for 4-5 models. The problem that I have is that I can't override base blueprint crud methods and I was curious if there is any way to do that in order to have custom CRUD methods for custom blueprints.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You've tagged this with `flask-restful`, but there's no obvious code using it. With `flask-restful` you make `Resource`'s and add these to Blueprints. You can define a base `Resource` which you can easily override the CRUD/REST operations. If that tag was a mistake, what you're after are [Pluggable Views](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/views/) , which is the basis of `flask-restful`, `flask-classful`, or `flask-classy`.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you very much for the comment, I will look into pluggable views